# Highlighting adjacent cell ten business days (exclude holidays) after the date found in the cell beside it

Tags: excel, date, formatting, cell, background-color

I have been trying to work on this with conditional formatting for a couple of days now to no avail

I have made it so that every time a "FILE NUMBER" is entered the cell to the right in grey shows the date it was entered in dd-Mmm-yy (ex. file number is C8 date is entered in D8).

Now what I need is a macro or conditional formatting that will highlight the "Motion" (B, E...) and "FILE NUMBER" (C, F...) cells in red when 10 ***business/work days have passed from the initial date entered in the corresponding grey cell (D, G, J...).

I wanted to use WORKDAY, but the cells are filled at random dates so I don't know what the start date would be. It's not a project with a duration. I want to use today, but it doesn't incorporate workdays.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the date you want to use as time=0 in D8,
and the cell you want to format is C8,
then select C8, and add a *Conditional Formatting* -> *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
and enter the formula `=TODAY() > WORKDAY(D8,10)`.

Notes:

1. **Using relative references in the conditional formatting** (e.g., D8 instead of $D$8) allows for using the same condition for an extended range, specified under *Conditional Formatting* -> *Manage Rules* -> *Applies To*. You might need to select absolute referencing for columns ($D8), rows (D$8) or both ($D$8; unlikely), depending on your needs. You may also need to define several Conditional Formats.
   Check [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/three-tips-for-using-excels-conditional-formatting-more-efficiently/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242411/how-can-i-copy-a-conditional-formatting-in-excel-2010-to-other-cells-which-is-b).
2. You might need to change the number `-10`.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much! This was super super helpful! I was having trouble extending the range of the Conditional formatting!

Comment: I would love to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation points