# If there's a value in the specified range, highlight row

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'm writing an application to copy values from a Word table to Excel. Every time a new table is found it will put those values in a new column. Most tables are identical, some aren't. I want a rule to highlight rows which have a value anywhere in the range AQ2 to JK1986.

I can highlight a row if a *specific* column has a value. Currently for a single column I use:

```
   =NOT($AQ2="")
```

but as you can imagine I don't want 250 such rules. Just removing the $ sign doesn't do anything. And making a formula stating $AQ2:$JK2 will always just give a true. I can also use the "Format only cells" to highlight the values but not the whole row, and I need it to highlight the whole row so I can see which documents have aberrant tables.

Is there a faster way to create a rule to highlight rows from AQ2 to JK1986 which have a value?

Comment: The question is somewhat confusing. A better description, and a figure of your worksheet used as a reference, will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight every row in the range 2:1986 where any cell in columns AQ to JK inclusive in that row is populated, use a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
 =COUNTA($AQ2:$JK2)>0
```

with highlighting of your choice and the Applies to range set to:

```
=$2:$1986
```

Answer (score 0):

You should likely use a combination of:

1. *Conditional Formatting* -> *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.
2. Relative references in the conditional formatting.
3. A suitable target range under *Conditional Formatting* -> *Manage Rules* -> *Applies To*.

You might need to define several rules (sometimes there is no way of avoiding it), but this will optimize the number of rules to its minimum.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196722/2707864), it will most certainly help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just use conditional formatting and set your parameters between those two values. Apologies if I do not understand your question correctly

Comment: If i place a statement saying =NOT($AQ2:$JK2) then all cells will be highlighted. Since it's always true, there IS a value in those cells.
And i need to see if there is a value in that selection, highlight the row where there is a value.